# SSRS Hidden parameter results in "Parameter X is missing a value"

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

First I would like to apologise for any mistake and misuse of the english language as it is not my natural language.

I built a few reports using SSRS. Each one are feeded through different stored procedures.
Each stored procedures has two parameters: id and date. When I display the report the parameter I only want to be visible the date that will be supplied by the user. The id should be hidden and with the default value of 1. So, I turned the parameter id to hidden and set up a default value with the value 1. Im setting the default value on a report's definition level instead on the datasets used to feed the reports. PLease see below the steps I have done:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wCyR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2IYj.png)

I've been through some websites(stackoverflow included) and I've seen similar issues. I followed the suggested tips but still no success.
Any help on this will be very appreciated.
Thanks

P.S. Im using VS2015 to design the reports and SQl Server 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more, my first instinct suggests that you have your parameters ordered incorrectly. If you have a parameter, P2, with a default value that is processed after a parameter without a default value, P1, and both parameters are hidden, then the report will fail citing that P1 is missing a value.

See my screenshot below as an example. You need to make sure that the parameters are loaded in the order, vertically, that they should be processed, especially if one parameter is dependent on another. Take a look at the ordering and leave a comment if you need further information.

**Revised based on Response in Commments**
Try opening the report manager via the Report Server web interface (http://[serverName]/[instanceName - reports is default]/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=/[directoryOfReport]). Click on the dropdown list beside the report name and choose manage. Check out the parameters tab and make sure the default is set properly. Sometimes, if you've messed with parameter properties numerous times in BIDS or report builder, the settings won't translate onto the server itself. Let me know if that fixes it.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping me.
Only one parameter is to be set up with a default value and to be hidden. the others are to be visible and typed by the user. Before the hidden parameter was the last one. I followed your advice and changed the stored procedure. NOw the parameter to be set with default value and hidden is the first. But still saying "parameter is missing a value"

Comment: @oliveiraj I revised my answer based on your comment. Take a look and see if that helps any.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the help. Yes it worked thanks. I did for all the reports and worked fine. The parameters were not set up properly there as they were in the report designer/VisualStudio. So I set up the default value there and worked fine. However i think this might be deployment issues because following you tip I decided to remove all the reports via the Report Server web interface and deploy them again. After that they were working fine.

Comment: This was explained to me by an SSRS guru as a fairly common bug. In my experience, it tends to happen more often with integers and even more often when you hardcode the value as an integer (i.e., 1) instead of using an expression to set it (i.e., =1). Those observations are largely anecdotal though, so do with them as you will.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I know the fact that I have to go through the Report Manager web interface and delete the reports to deploy them after sounds anecdotal but it works. And so far was the only way I found to make it works. Thanks.